# Get the function prototype using emacs

Tags: c, function, emacs, elisp, prototype

I got a C program edited with emacs.

The C program is not important it looks like

```
int main(int ac, char **av)
{
....
}
int func(void){...}
int anotherfunc(int a, char c, void *data){...}
```

can we have a Elisp function which parse the current buffer with those functions and catch the function prototype ?

I already use etags but I just have

```
int main(
int func(
```

But i would like have

```
int main(int ac, char **av)
int func(void)
int anotherfunc(int a, char c,  void *data)
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking at c-eldoc mode - http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CEldocMode